# How can i query with ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield, m2m

If i know company_id, how can i call a query list department, each department have list user and each user has username and staff_id?
Example models and output below

```
class User(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)

class Company(models.Model)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User', through='User_Company',related_name="companies")

class Department(models.Model)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User', through='User_Department',related_name="departments")

class User_Department(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="ud_membership")
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="ud_membership")

class User_Company(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="uc_membership")
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="uc_membership")
    staff_id = =models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

---

I want data output with this format:

[image]

Comment: can you do elaborate on your question...

Comment: i added information for my question

Answer (score 0):

You can find the departments that have at least one useer in common with:

```
Department.objects.filter(users__companies=company_id).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** clause [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will prevent returing the `Department`s multiple times. Without `.distinct()`, each `Department` will be returned that many times as there are common users.